# incorrect form serialization with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, serialization

On my CMS, I use marked to public posts, and on form marked put generated html into textarea, when I submit for first time (creating of the new post) form is serialized correctly.

My CMS after creation append's one input (type text) with some specific info and button's to edit and delete, the process is the same but when I try to serialize form:

```
$(e).serialize() // e ----> '#form'
```

I see the old value (original) of my textarea, and only after submitting (editing) I get the correct serialized info.

[image: example of bad serializing]

I have live preview, so textarea always has recent content. . .

Where can be the problem?

Because if I try to edit post (acessing directly from list of post) everything work's and form is always serialized correctly.

code of function:

```
var form_submit = function(e, f){
    console.log('FORM')
    e.preventDefault();
    NProgress.start();
    console.log($(f).serialize()+'&req_type=put')
    $.post(
        f.action, $(f).serialize()+'&req_type=put'
    ).success(function(d){
        // ....
    }).error(function(d){
        // ....
    })
}
```

Comment: Without seeing more code I can't be sure, but I imagine it's because you're storing the form data to `e` with the original value, and you serialize that variable, instead of the current form values.

Comment: @sharf sure, I added full function, and it's works correctly if I edit the post from the original post editting page, not from transformed to edition page . . . .

Comment: Is `#full_mark`'s default value 3s or 4s?

Comment: @sharf 4s.
example, if I create the textarea with 1s, I will see correct serialization, but when I will edit for first time and change to 2s, I will see 1s, but if I change another time to 3s and submit, I will see 2s...
I always see correct serialization after second submitting

Comment: Whenever the serialization is happening, it is either doing it using an old element, or it is happening before the change is propagating.

Comment: @sharf I fond a problem... after submitting, textarea stop change the "viewed" text, because preview still work.
[see this](http://s017.radikal.ru/i423/1505/5e/5b97be07aa07.png) .

Comment: @sharf I don't know why that is the solution after submitting : `$('#full_mark').val($('#full_mark').text());` . thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

After submitting I need to update the "viewed" text of `textarea`,

[image: solution]

so here is a solution for this strange problem....

```
$('#full_mark').val($('#full_mark').text());
```